# Disabled input text type with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, text, input, types

I'm having a little problem, i'm trying to make a disabled "input text type" enabled with a text in it.

```
function newForm(){
document.getElementsByName("name1").disabled = false;
document.getElementsByName("name1").value="TEST";
}
```

with this

```
<div id="passengers">
<div id="form">
    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th></th><th>Name</th><th>LastName</th><th>Date of Birth</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <form id="formulaire" action="">
        <tr><th>Passenger #1</th><th><input type="text" name="name1" tabindex="1" disabled="true"/></th><th><input type="text" name="lastname1" tabindex="2" disabled="true"/></th><th><input type="text" name="date1" tabindex="3" disabled="true"/></th></tr>
    </table>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="New" onclick="newForm()"/><input type="submit" value="Send" disabled="true"/><input type="submit" value="Modify" disabled="true"/></form>
</div>
```

Comment: `getElementsByName` returns a collection of objects, not one element..

Comment: Use `input type="button"` for the "New" button so it doesn't try to submit the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, change the input type of the button, from `submit` to `button`:

```
<input type="button" value="New" onclick="newForm()"/>
```

As your function has nothing to do with submitting the form (and `submit` will cause unwanted behaviour).

Secondly, `getElementsByName` returns a collection of objects, *not* one element. Target the element by accessing the first element using `[0]`:

```
function newForm(){
  document.getElementsByName("name1")[0].disabled = false;
  document.getElementsByName("name1")[0].value="TEST";
}
```

[**Here's a working jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/L4EUD/)

Answer (score 1):

[getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName) returns a collection of elements try this

```
document.getElementsByName('name1')[0].disabled = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but it work for like 1 sec, the inputtexttype thing become "enabled' and the text TEST appear but 1 seconds later, it's disabled again and there no text.